# Position an element on each corner no matter the size of the svg

Tags: svg

I'm trying to create an SVG that has an element in each corner. I want the svg to be scaleable, whilst the corner elements **retain their size** and **aspect ratio**... whilst sticking to the corners.

I feel like with a lot of javascript fiddling, this could be done. But I really feel this could be done with some clever css and a good understanding of how SVG's actually work.

This is an example of how I'd expect it to work: [**Demo Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/marknotton/o5r1e5xL/2/). This is just html and css.

```
div { width:40px; height:40px; position:absolute; 
  &:nth-of-type(1) { top:0; left:0; background-color:red;}
  &:nth-of-type(2) { top:0; right:0; background-color:blue;}
  &:nth-of-type(3) { bottom:0; left:0; background-color:green;}
  &:nth-of-type(4) { bottom:0; right:0; background-color:yellow;}
}
```

**This is where I got to before finally coming here: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marknotton/qq40vcqo/)**

```
<svg version="1.1" id="circle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100"  xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none">

  <svg id="top-left" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <rect width="20" height="20" fill="red" style="y:0; x:0"/>
  </svg>

  <svg id="top-right" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMin meet">
    <rect width="20" height="20" fill="blue" style="y:0; x:calc(100% - 20px)"/>
  </svg>

  <svg id="bottom-left" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax meet">
    <rect width="20" height="20" fill="green" style="y:calc(100% - 20px); x:0"/>
  </svg>

  <svg id="bottom-right" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet">
    <rect width="20" height="20" fill="yellow" style="y:calc(100% - 20px); x:calc(100% - 20px)"/>
  </svg>  

</svg>
```

Any insight would be greatly appriciated.

Cheers,

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the corner elements are symmetrical (left-to-right and top-to-bottom) then you could use a little trick of placing the right (or bottom) elements at x=-100% (or y=-100%) and applying a scale transform with sx=-1 (or sy=-1).

```html
<svg x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <rect id="top-left" x="0%" y="0%" width="20" height="20" fill="red"/>
    <rect id="top-right" x="-100%" y="0%" width="20" height="20" fill="green" transform="scale(-1,1)"/>
    <rect id="bottom-left" x="0%" y="-100%" width="20" height="20" fill="blue" transform="scale(1,-1)"/>
    <rect id="bottom-right" x="-100%" y="-100%" width="20" height="20" fill="yellow" transform="scale(-1,-1)"/>
</svg>
```

Note that this trick only works for the special case when the corner elements are symmetrical.

Answer (score 2):

If you know you are only going to need to scale in one direction. In other words the SVG is fixed in either with or height.  Then you can do something like the following, which is designed for a fixed height of 100px.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="none">

  <svg id="top-left" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 20 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <rect width="20" height="20" fill="red"/>
  </svg>

  <svg id="top-right" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 20 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMin meet">
    <rect width="20" height="20" fill="blue"/>
  </svg>

  <svg id="bottom-right" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 20 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax meet">
    <rect y="80" width="20" height="20" fill="green"/>
  </svg>

  <svg id="bottom-left" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 20 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet">
    <rect y="80" width="20" height="20" fill="yellow"/>
  </svg>  

</svg>
```