# Keep close button in upper right corner even when modal scales

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap modal and the close button is an image. When the modal size changes depending on the viewport, I want the close button to always stay in the top right corner of the modal

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal modal fade">
    <a class="close-modal" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick=closeModalBox()>
        <img src="images/close.png" width="39" >
    </a>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" style="position: relative;">
            <div class="modal-body" >
              <!-- code -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
.close-modal {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 10;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 1%;
    left: 77%;
} 
.modal-content{
    position: relative; 
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the html structure, see example below, to keep the close button in the correct position. also refer to this link. [Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It was exactly the issue. The close button was not placed right. Thanks for your suggestion @Munei

Answer (score 1):

With Bootstrap v5.3 you can set the button position to be absolute without additional CSS:

```
    <div class="modal-header position-relative pb-0">
      <h1 class="modal-title fs-1 luckiest" id="menu-modal-label">Menu</h1>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close position-absolute top-0 end-0 m-2" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
```

- `position-relative` set the container as relative
- `position-absolute` set the close button as absolute (in the container)
- `top-0` set the close button to the top of the container
- `end-0` set the close button to the right of the container
- `m-2` set some margin to leave some space around the button

Here is the result:
[image: Close button always on top right in modals]

Comment: Perfect! This solved it for me in BS5

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to keep the button while scrolling down?
If that is the case use the "sticky" variable,

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/

Comment: No I mean keep the button in the top right corner no matter the size of the modal . the modal rescales depending on the viewport

Comment: i found a similar question on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190523/position-an-element-on-each-corner-no-matter-the-size-of-the-svg, Maybe this helps you out further

Comment: Careful with sticky as it is not supported in IE.

Answer (score -1):

You are using percentage values which will change visually when going between device sizes. Set these to fixed values so your close button will always be at a specific spot relative to the device size. Also, because you are using absolute positioning you can take advantage of the 'right' attribute instead.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_right.asp

```
.close-modal {
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
opacity: 1;
z-index: 10;
cursor: pointer;
top: 50px; // define your value here
right: 80px; // define your value here
}
```